# how can i replace mean instead of missing values in python

Tags: python, pandas, nan

In the code below, i'm trying to replace mean instead of missing values but i can't get a result for my attempts because this data includes special characters which is "?". When there is no question marks in the data this code works `data.fillna(data.mean())`. When i tried to impute method, i got the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot use mean strategy with non-numeric data:
> could not convert string to float:

Also this data includes string columns with missing values, how can i fix missing values in the string columns (column rbc for example)?

here is my data: https://easyupload.io/te2mbc

````
path = ("C:\\Users\\bbb\\Desktop\\ccc\\group5data.txt")
names = ["age","bp","sg","al","su","rbc","pc","pcc","ba",
         "bgr","bu","sc","sod","pot","hemo","pcv","wc",
         "rc","htn","dm","cad","appet","pe","ane","class"]
data = pd.read_csv(path, names=names)```
````

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? you want to replace the ? with the mean of that column? or the mean of the entire dataframe? also, what do you want the text to be in rbc instead of Nan?

Comment: You have many lines with an unwanted '\t' character in data (lines 38 41 65 66 67 77 89 134 139 163 186 189 195 215 231). You have 2 lines end with comma (lines 70 73) so Pandas drop them (expected 25 fields, saw 26). I think you really need to clean data before use it with Pandas

Comment: @JonathanLeon i'm trying to fix as many data as i can. yes i want to replace ? with the mean of that column and i want to remove rows with string NaNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have '?' characters in columns 'sod' and 'pot' make pandas
parse those columns as strings, so even if you do

```
df.replace('?', np.nan)
```

the column will have both (float) NaNs and strings, so pandas won't be able to
calculate a mean() for it. I believe this is what causes your ValueError.

So try converting those columns to float (not int, because np.nan is float):

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/a/sw/group5data.txt', error_bad_lines=False, names=names)
df = df.replace('?', np.nan)
df.loc[:, 'sod':'pot'] = df.loc[:, 'sod':'pot'].astype(float)
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

The NaNs have now been replaced with each columns's mean (of course, the
columns are now float, instead of the original int, but that should be easy to
fix).

Answer (score 0):

Your data consists of both numerical and non numeric columns, inorder to `fillna` with mean you need to select just the numerical columns

### Select numeric columns.

```
data = data.select_dtypes('number')
```

### Fill numeric columns with mean.

```
data[data.columns] = data.fillna(a.mean())
```